# Ejecucion de un hilo, despues de otro

Tags: java, hilos

tengo dos hilos, y necesito que el uno se inicie, cuando el primero acaba. ¿Como podria hacerlo? He probado alguna cosa, en el segundo hilo, el que quiero que se ejecute despues del primeor, puse hilo2.join(); . No se si eso servira, pero lei que funcionaba.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lanzas el segundo justo antes de terminar la ejecución del método `run` del primero?

Comment: Pon lo que hayas intentado y los resultados/problemas que encontraste. "_No se si eso servira, pero lei que funcionaba_" es una mala señal en una pregunta, si leíste que funcionaba, ¿por qué no lo probaste antes de publicar la pregunta? Si realmente funcionaba, te ahorras la pregunta, y si no funciona, al menos tienes código que compartir y con el que podemos trabajar.

Answer (score 1):

El enfoque mas sencillo seria utilizar `.join()`para esperar el fin de su ejecución antes de iniciar el segundo thread.

La idea es invocar el `.start()`del segundo thread luego de la llamada al `.join()` del primer thread. De esa forma te garantizas que al iniciar el `t2` la ejecución del `run()` del `t1` ha finalizado.

```
class MiHilo implements Runnable(){
     @Override
      public void run(){
         // method logic...
     } 
 }

Thread t1 = new Thread(new MiHilo ()); 
t1.start();
t1.join(); 
Thread t2 = new Thread(new MiHilo ());
t2.start();
t2.join();
```

Comment: No digo que no funcione, pero con este código realmente no hay diferencia entre usar *threads* o sencillamente poner dos bloques de código uno detrás de otro.